# Python: How can I assign string representations of operators to mathematical operators using a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, user-defined-functions

My aim is to create a UDF that does simple arithmetic. I want the function to take 2 values, and then a string representation of an operator, for example 'mulitiply' and perform the operator on x to y. This is my first time attempting this, excuse the mess.

```
def_myArithmetic(x, y, op):
     op={'multiply': *, 'divide': /, 'add': +, 'subtract':-}
     **some loop**
         **return calculation**
```

what I have managed so far

```
import operator
def do_arithmetic(x, y, op):
  op={'multiply': operator.multiply,'divide': operator.divide,'add': operator.add ,'subtract': operator.subtract}
  for i in range(x,y):
     print (x, y)
```

using this bloc of code returns an error when calling the function.

Im aware this dictionary does not work. And i believe its to do with having multiple keys within one reference ?

I believe im somewhere near the right lines but clearly have no idea how to write this. It would be very helpful to have something to reference when I try to implement the rules of my choosing.

Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module. `operator.add`, `operator.mul`, etc.

Comment: may i ask for an example within a UDF?

Comment: `{'multiply': operator.mul, ...}`

Comment: Your dictionary is the right approach, you just need to use those functions as the values.

Comment: that is very helpful, thank you Barmar

Comment: import operator
def do_arithmetic(x, y, op):
  op={'multiply': operator.multiply,'divide': operator.divide,'add': operator.add ,'subtract': operator.subtract}
  for i in range(x,y):
     return (x, op, y)

Thoughts?

Comment: Don't use the same variable for the dictionary and the parameter.

Comment: You shouldn't use `return`, that will end the function and stop the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary variable is replacing the `op` parameter. Use a different name for this.

You need to use the string argument as a key to access the corresponding dictionary element.

You need to call the operator function, not just put it in a tuple with the arguments.

There's no reason for the `for` loop.

There's no `operator.multiply`, it's `operator.mul`. Find the full list [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

```
def do_arithmetic(x, y, op):
    operations = {
        'multiply': operator.mul,
        'divide': operator.truediv,
        'add': operator.add,
        'subtract': operator.sub
    }
    return operations[op](x, y)
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thanks a lot Barmar!. I just started coding only 4 days ago. This has put of a lot of reading into practice.